# Ionic 2 not updating UI

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have problem with Ionic 2 not updating my UI when I change a variable.

html:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let event of mEvents (click)="onEventCardClick(event)">
    <ion-card-content ion-item>
        <span class="eventTitle">{{ event.title }}</span> <br/>
        <span class="relativeDate">{{ event.getRelativeTimeString() }}</span>
        <ion-badge item-end>{{ event.reservationsCount }}</ion-badge>
        <ion-badge *ngIf="event.hasUnreadMessages" color="danger" item-end>{{ event.unreadMessagesCount }}</ion-badge>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

end from ts file:

```
this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe((notification:NotificationData) => {
    if(!this.navCtrl.isActive(this.viewCtrl))
        return;

    notification.event = JSON.parse(notification.event);
    notification.reservation = JSON.parse(notification.reservation);
    notification.reservation_message = JSON.parse(notification.reservation_message);

    let eventId: number = notification.event.id;
    for(let i=0; i<this.mEvents.length; i++) {
        if(this.mEvents[i].id == eventId) {
            this.mEvents[i].unreadMessagesCount++;
            this.mEvents[i].hasUnreadMessages = true;
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is, I send a push notification from my server. i receive message successfully and update corresponding object (Event). But this last `ion-badge` element in `ion-card` does not shows up. It is still "hidden". However if I interact with UI, it suddenly shows up.

How can I achieve instant UI update? I read in some articles about NgZone but half of them says that is should not be used and the other half says that I should use it ...

Comment: Just note: avoid binding 2 ways with function, because Angular won't know when it changes so it's called every smallest stuff change. And your `*ngFor` miss `"` or your code miss it also.

Comment: @ThienHoang what changes to my code do you suggest instead of *ngFor. I am pretty much new to angular, actually I started working with ionic with no knowledge of angular at all and I am learning on the fly

Answer (score 5):

Use the [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef). It detects changes in variables and updates the UI. Create the `private ref:ChangeDetectorRef` in the constructor then call `this.ref.detectChanges()` whenever you need to update the UI when your variable changes.

Comment: It turns out, that FCM when dispatches messages to my subscribes runs out of current NgZone, what ever that be and however it does, but it runs outside of that. If I wrap code that changes variables inside `this.zone.run(() => { /* code here */ }` everything works.